# Is it possible to get/set version of IE rendering engine in powershell?

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, powershell-2.0

This is how I can get version of IE in PS

```
(Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer').Version
```

Returns 9.11.9600.18163

Here's how I init IE for some some custom actions:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
```

Is there a way how to set which IE version is used for rendering in PS? Like in Dev tools? 5,7,8,9,10,Edge? I'm affraid that on Win7 it's limited to IE9.

Thanks

Comment: Dev tools in IE doesn't allow you to launch different versions of IE. It allows you to modify the layout/rendering engine to *act* like a different version of IE - huge difference.

Comment: I belive that every new version of IE contains rendering engines of previous versions (I was told so on some MS training few years ago). And for me it makes sense because hacking every new engine to act as previous engines could be really complicated.  My current version of IE is Edge (11), but PS query (see above) to windows register returns version 9.

Comment: That's probably true, but you don't launch version X of IE, you launch the newest and configure that to use and old engine. Also IE 11 is NOT Edge. Edge is a different product

Comment: Yes, but latest version version of IE (11) is called Edge (dev tools) and we're talking about Win7 (not Win10). Let's beging a constructive discussion please - how to set rendering engine version of IE in powershell?